# How to stop triggering introjs after first walkthrough?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, intro.js

I'm using *[introjs](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/)*.

But when a user ends the intro, then refreshes the page, *introjs* starts up again.

Is there a way to only show a walkthrough once per user?

For example I have it where when a user first signs into my website - *introjs* will popup. I only want it to pop up for that initial welcome.

### Potential Solutions

1. Maybe there is a way to trigger *introjs* via the create action like one would with a flash message?
2. I could replicate all my header, sidebar, and challenges section code into pages/tutorial.html.erb and make a route www.websitename.com/tutorial, but then that would be a lot of code to duplicate and then whenever I change something in the site I would have to change it in tutorial too.
3. Is there a way to adjust this javascript method in application.js to trigger only once per user `$(function () {
   introJs().start() })`?

I just use `data-intro=""` for each step of the walkthrough.

Comment: Server side storage - MySQL, redis, etc. client side strategies won't help you as soon as the user clears their browser cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your application/webpage to remember that the user has already gone through your tutorial.

There are a few ways you can do that. For a start, you can use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

The gist is that after the user finishes, or otherwise exits your tutorial, you can store a descriptive value to the user's client, by using one of the above methods, and on page load you should first check if this value exists and act accordingly.

EDIT: As mentioned in comments, you will need a server side approach as well.

Comment: That doesn't help much, there's no persistence in your solution

Comment: It is sort of persistence, but you are right. Removed that part.